# Corrosion of a galvanic couple made with silver and gold

Tags: electrochemistry, metal

If a bangle is made out of gold and silver, connected with each-other would there be corrosion happening?
If so, can it be explained using the galvanic series?

Also do those metals undergo oxidation under normal conditions?

Comment: A very interesting question - I wonder if the carat (varying ratio of Au and Ag) value affects the rate of corrosion (if any are present)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you state, though silver is not very reactive, silver *jewelry* would corrode more rapidly when in contact with gold and a bit of sweat as electrolyte. Though the difference in electronegativity of *pure* gold and *pure* silver is [0.15V, and is considered acceptably corrosion resistant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_corrosion), commercial jewelry contains copper and other metals in the alloys. There is clearly evident corrosion in [photos of copper/silver jewelry](http://ganoksin.com/blog/binnion/2012/11/23/copper-and-silver-rings-may-not-be-such-a-good-idea/). According to the [Victoria and Albert Museum](http://www.vam.ac.uk/content/articles/c/caring-for-your-metal-objects/) staff, "All metals, with the exception of 24 carat gold, suffer the effects of corrosion."

However, in a bangle, physical abrasion is likely to cause more damage and loss of material than galvanic corrosion. Wear the jewelry and enjoy it, but it will not last forever.